# Bash script for searching directory and moving files to a new directory, deleting any copies

Tags: bash, file, hard-drive

I have a 2TB hard drive full of backed up data, including hundreds of movies, most of which have been copied several times due to sequential back-ups of the same HD. The hard drive is organized as a list of back-up folders, and every back-up contains a movies folder that has all the movies that were on my laptop HD at the time of the back-up.

I'd like to create a new movies folder and move all movies from every "movies" subfolder into the new one, making sure not to move the same movie twice. How can I go about this if I want to do everything via Bash?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each copy of a movie in various folders has the same name and all have the same extension, let's say `.divx`,  you can use `find` to find them and copy them to a different folder and then delete the old folders.

```
find / -iname "*.divx" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv "{}" /path/to/new_folder/
```

Or you can loop through all the files and copy them to new_folder only if they are not already present. If already present, delete other copies. Something like this:

```
for file in $(find . -iname "*.divx" -type f)
do
filename=$(basename ${file})
if [ ! -f ./movie/${filename} ]; then
    mv ${file} ./movie/${filename}
else
    rm ${file}
fi
done
```

Comment: I'd suggest `mv -n "$file" ./movie/ && rm -f "$file"` as a shorter equivalent of your loop body. And note that this code is broken WRT spaces or similar things in the filenames.

Comment: @user2719058 I agree. The first should handle filename with spaces. Second, I have just given as an example.

Comment: all copies of a particular movie are identical, but various movies have different extensions like mp4, mkv etc.

Comment: @user3225710: You can specify multiple file name patterns, e.g. `find . \( -name file1 -o -name file2 -o ... \)`