# Moving folders on external hard drive using Bash - Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, bash, hard-drive

This is somewhat of a follow up to:

[Bash script for searching directory and moving files to a new directory, deleting any copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232430/bash-script-for-searching-directory-and-moving-files-to-a-new-directory-deletin)

My bash script now attempts to move folders to the specified directory and delete the old one. However, the bash script returns a list of "operation not permitted" errors instead. I have tried everything, including all variants of advice found here:

https://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-reports-operation-not-permitted-on-osx

I've manually unlocked the drive itself, and the drive is formatted as mac os extended, but nothing has made the slightest difference. I can manually add or extract files from the drive by dragging them, but not en masse using a script. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm using the latest Mavericks. Here's my script:

```
echo "Organizing files!"
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
MOV=$(find ./Backups.backupdb -maxdepth 4 -type d -iname "*movies*")
for filename in $MOV ; do
for file in ${filename}/* ; do
    base=$(basename ${file})
    if [ "$base" == "Series" ] ;
        then
        mv -n "$file" ./Seriesholder/ && rm -f "$file"

    elif [ ! -d ./MovieLibrary/${base} ] ;
        then
        mv -n "$file" ./MovieLibrary/ && rm -f "$file"
        echo "file added"
    else
        mv "$file" ~./Trash
        echo "file trashed"
    fi
done
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
echo "Archive organized"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on your hard drive partition, can you unlock the lock at the bottom? 
[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3695988?tstart=0)